# error: request for member ‘getdata’ in ‘*(& it)->__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<st**, std::vector<st*> >::operator->()’, *(it)->getdata();

Tags: c++, stl

Here is the code I am trying to creat a N object and store it into vector array. And trying to display the data of each object using Vector class . But Compiler is throwing an error. How to fixed it ???

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef struct st SLL;
struct st
{
    int id;
    char Name[10];
    void setdata();
    void getdata();
    SLL * creatObject();
};

void SLL :: setdata()
{
    cout << "Enter the Data\n";
    cin >> id>> Name;
}
void SLL:: getdata()
{
    cout << id << " " << Name << endl;
}

SLL * SLL:: creatObject()
{
    SLL * newObject = new SLL();
    newObject->setdata();
    newObject->getdata();
    return newObject;
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<SLL*> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(creatObject());
    }
    std::vector<SLL*> ::iterator it ;
    for(it = v.begin(); it != v.end() ;it++)
    {
        *(it)->getdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `(*it)->getdata();`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: When i compile this code , i am getting error                                                                                                           error: request for member ‘getdata’ in ‘*(& it)->__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<st**, std::vector<st*> >::operator->()’, which is of pointer type ‘st*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
   *(it)->getdata();

Comment: Yes, you should write `(*it)`, not `*(it)`.

Comment: I am getting one more error , i.e.n                                                                              error: ‘creatObject’ was not declared in this scope
   v.push_back(creatObject());

Comment: Because `creatObject` is a member function of `SLL`.